# File deleting error

Tags: c#, file, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877889/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

I have a PDF file in my application i want to delete that file. when I try to delete the file it give the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

The code is as follows

```
if (File.Exists(sDownloadFile))
             File.Delete(sDownloadFile);
```

How can I delete this file?

Comment: what type of application did you used?

Comment: still not clear your question.you only post the delete fun.Before that what you doing in that file?How you opened that file? If may shared that file or not? can you post the source code? or at least post the fun for how you opened that file?

Comment: When i click a button to delete the file I just checks the file is existing and then deletes

Comment: This happens when i try to download the file and closes the window. and then clicks the delete button quickly say about after 2-3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The reason of error is bit simple. you have open a file but not properly close it. the instance remain live in memory.

write `.Close()` and `.Dispose()` method to release memory.

sample code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321163/1495442):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile("https://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png", "Foo.png");
FileStream fooStream;
using (fooStream = new FileStream("foo.png", FileMode.Open))
{
    // do stuff
}
File.Move("foo.png", "foo2.png");
```

Comment: I am new to files Please give me a sample